# Material For Heat Riser

Tags: building-materials

I'm in the process of building my first Rocket Stove, that will give me highly sustainable energy (if one considers burning wood to be sustainable).

For the heat riser I'm looking for heat resistant materials. Must I choose a metal or a mineral heat riser?

Would be nice to have a few references.

See the following post for a Rocket Stove design: https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/3005/1688

Comment: Welcome to sustainability.SE! Perhaps you could provide a link or a little explanation for those of us not familiar with what a Rocket Stove is?

Comment: Hi @SimonW, see this post http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/3005/1688

Comment: Great! Perhaps edit that link into the question?

Comment: [This related question](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/3120/99) now has an answer which may also be helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were to build a Rocket Stove for the long run, then I would go for a mineral. Not just a mineral, but a fire resistant composition such as *Grog, also known as fire sand and chamotte<sup>1</sup>*. The reason for me to choose so, stems from the experience the following two YouTube pages had.

### Bigelow Brook Farm

The following screenshot is taken from the last post of *Bigelow Brook Farms<sup>2</sup>* YouTube page, which covers the build (and re-build) of a Rocket Stove in detail and shows a totally corroded iron heat riser:
[image]

This has happened over a course of a winter and intensive usage. Nonetheless it shows that intense heat can even corrode the toughest material. Bigelow Brook Farm has re-build the heat riser with fire bricks and will post an update on that in due time.

### Zero Fossil Fuel

Has made as a very detailed series on how to build a Rocket Stove. At 1'18" in the *video<sup>3</sup>*, he makes reference to the fact that he was strongly advised against the use of steel.
[image]

### References

1. [Grog (clay)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grog_(clay))
2. [Bigelow Brook Farm](http://youtu.be/7RyvsZD1_CU)
3. [Zero Fossil Fuel](http://youtu.be/-rcJ_lp-bYI)

### Note

I'm not affiliated to either of the YouTube pages mentioned in this post.